# Column date filtering in vaadin not working

Tags: java, hibernate, vaadin, vaadin7

I have problem with date filtering.
Others column in tables are filtering, but date column is not.

Here is an example of filter, I have one searchbox for filtering all columns:

```
filter = new Or(new Like("NumberOf", "%"+tfGlobalSearch.getValue().toString()+"%", false), 
                new Like ("Type","%"+tfGlobalSearch.getValue().toString()+"%", false),
                new Like("Date created", "%"+tfGlobalSearch.getValue().toString()+"%", false)                                                   
                                );
f.addContainerFilter(filter);
```

Date is in format: 09.06.2016 14:52:57, and when i type for example "09." and search it, it doesn't filter at all.

I dont know where is the problem :/

Comment: The Like filtered only works with properties of type String. What is the type of the property "Date created"?

Comment: @A. Meier - its java.util.date format, when i put new SimpleStringFilter for date it filters only for numbers. If i enter for example "09.06" it does not filter correct. It seems that "." makes problem

Comment: You need to override property/column toString method to returs the date in a 09.06.2016 14:52:57 format

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you write your own DateFilter (implement Container.Filter). There you compare your string representation of your date with the pattern you have initialized your filter with. It's then basically a variation of the Like filter implementation.